# How to do conditional defining of key in an object in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Suppose I want to create an object with keys as USD and non-USD. Like Below:

```
    let obj = {
                USD: {
                   sourceValue: 100
                   destinationValue: 10
                }, 
                non-USD: {
                  sourceValue: 10
                   destinationValue: 100
                }
              }
```

Except here, instead of non-USD, I should be able to pass any currency, like SGD or HKD and I should get result of non-USD currency.

so, if I wrote `obj[currency].sourceValue` and `currency=HKD` then I should get `10`

I don't want to use `obj[1].sourceValue` as currency value is dynamic.

Also, I don't want to use `if(currency!='USD') index=1` and then `obj[index].sourceValue`

So, my question is, what should I write at place of non-USD while defining object? I checked computation names, but I am not sure, how will I pass long currency array as key name and filter USD out of it?

Comment: Check out [`computed property names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) - basically you use square brackets around a variable which described the key

Comment: "I checked computation names, but I am not sure, how will I pass long currency array as key name and filter USD out of it?" I don't think those even solve the problem that you are trying to solve, but I also don't think there is a way in js to do exactly what you want and how you want to do it. So maybe elaborate a bit on why a getter call is not okay, why does it have to be a key lookup in an object?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a function that accepts US currency, and then calculates what that currency is for all known currencies? That part is easy, but you need access to an API for that because that information fluctuates wildly.

Comment: You can define it like you already stated assuming currency is a string. `obj[currency] = {  sourceValue: 10, destinationValue: 100}`; `currency = "USD";`. What needs clarification is what you want to achieve. Especially the part about passing array of currencies as key name. Example would be great.

Comment: Do you want conditional defining or conditional getting? All the answers below are about conditional getting. Note that conditional getting is defining conditional keys (meaning keys will be dynamic) which is the opposite of conditionally defining keys (meaning after dynamically defining the object keys are static)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an option in js/ts that would have the key lookup syntax (like `obj[currency]`) and do the behavior that you want, while keeping the object `obj` "plain".

But there are options that do what you want with some modifications to the `obj` and/or with a different call syntax. (The only way that I can think of that would keep the `obj` completely untouched would require some changes to the currencies then.)

### Option 1: add a get function call

```
const obj1 = {
    get: function(currency) {
        return this[currency === "USD" ? "USD" : "non-USD"]    
    },
    USD: {
        sourceValue: 100,
        destinationValue: 10
    }, 
    "non-USD": {
        sourceValue: 10,
        destinationValue: 100
    }
}
```

Or if you cannot change the object's source use `Object.assign`.
Here you can decide if you want to mutate the original object (`Object.assign(target, ...)`) or create a new one with `Object.assign({}, target, ...)`

```
const addGetter = (target) => Object.assign({}, target, {
    get: (currency) => target[currency === "USD" ? "USD" : "non-USD"] 
})

const obj1 = addGetter(obj) // <-- pass in the original obj
```

Usage: `obj1.get(currency).sourceValue`

### Option 2: using a Proxy

Proxy [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), [support](https://caniuse.com/?search=proxy)

Offers the key lookup syntax that you want, but imo, this approach is a bit error-prone, because any access (indexed, by key or property) other than "USD" will return the "non-USD" values. Also the object gets wrapped, which hides object details when logging (`console.log(obj)`) in some consoles.

```
const useProxy = (obj) => new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (target, currency) => target[currency === "USD" ? "USD" : "non-USD"]
})

const obj2 = useProxy(obj) // <-- pass in the original obj
```

Usage: `obj2[currency].sourceValue`

### Demo

Check the code comments and the console output

```js
const addGetter = (target) => Object.assign({}, target, {
    get: (currency) => target[currency === "USD" ? "USD" : "non-USD"] 
})

const useProxy = (obj) => new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (target, currency) => target[currency === "USD" ? "USD" : "non-USD"]
})

const obj = {
    USD: {
        sourceValue: 100,
        destinationValue: 10
    }, 
    "non-USD": {
        sourceValue: 10,
        destinationValue: 100
    }
}

// Option 1
const obj1 = addGetter(obj)

// Option 2
const obj2 = useProxy(obj)

const c = ["USD", "EUR", "HKD", "non-USD"]

console.log("obj1.get(currency).sourceValue", c.map(currency => currency + " -> " + obj1.get(currency).sourceValue))

console.log("obj2[currency].sourceValue", c.map(currency => currency + " -> " + obj2[currency].sourceValue))
// Option 2 feels a bit error-prone, as any other access will return the fallback value for "non-USD"
console.log("obj2.length", c.map(currency => obj2.length))
console.log("obj2.randomProp", c.map(currency => obj2.randomProp))
```

Answer (score 0):

You ll actually need to use the if else like condition.
say like this

```
const key = currency == "USD" ? "USD" : "non-USD";
// and then get the data like this
obj[currency].sourceValue
```